# Small monitor for Retropie

Tags: monitors, hdmi, raspberry-pi

I am looking for a small monitor for my Retropie (it's basically a all in one console emulator OS for the Raspberry Pi).

What the monitor must have:

- HDMI port
- Low price (<£100)
- Raspberry Pi 2 compatibility

What the monitor should have:

- Built-in audio
- Small size (≤10in)
- Shipping to Estonia

Comment: is audio optional?(this is the tricky bit) Is a 'bare' panel ok/does it need to be standalone or have a mount/frame?

Comment: A 'bare' panel is OK if you can't find a frame for it, maybe I can craft one out of LEGO® bricks. Also, I want audio because Retropie seems to have problems with the Pi's audio jack. But if you can't find one, it's OK without.

Comment: The [HDMIPi](http://hdmipi.com/) looks like it would be good here but not sure about audio is included or not. They don't use HDMI but do use DSI, which is built-in to the Pi. It's a touchscreen. You can get them with mounts although I don't know whether they ship to Estonia but they are sold at several different retailers. Hope this helps and sorry it doesn't quite meet all your requirements!

Comment: Details on the HDMIPi seem to be scarce. I don't know whether it supports the RPi 2 out of the box but I found this [back plate upgrade kit](http://shop.cyntech.co.uk/products/hdmipi-b-back-plate) for the Pi2 but I have no idea whether this is official.

Comment: Found some more information about using this with a Pi 2 and Retropie [here](http://blog.petrockblock.com/forums/topic/trying-retropie-on-official-raspberry-7-display/)

Comment: Looks like you may have to make the display yourself using parts provided?

Answer (score 2):

There's quite a few similar ones but I used [this](http://www.dx.com/p/10-1-digital-ips-screen-1280-x-800-drive-board-for-raspberry-pcduino-cubieboard-black-275804) as a secondary screen for a few years. It got somewhat roughly handled, but if you plan ahead and mount it correctly (and not try to work on it while its plugged in as I did) its a good monitor, which is remarkably good looking. No audio as far as I can tell.

DX tends to ship anywhere and shipping's part of the list price.

SO..

HDMI Port? Check. Also has composite or VGA if needed

Low price? Somewhere around 60 euros

Works with a RPI? Sure

No built in audio though, and its JUST over 10 inches.

There's a lower resolution 7 inch option as well I believe, which would be cheaper, but its something janky like 640x480.